# Selenium C# - verifying the drop down was selected item

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I have selected the drop-down 
now i want to verify the selected drop down is correct using Assert

I have noticed that the selected item has attribute "selected"

var ftpTransDropdown = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("FtpTransmittalMethods"));
            var selectFtpTransDrpdwn = new SelectElement(ftpTransDropdown);
            selectFtpTransDrpdwn.SelectByText("NIHMS-PubMed Central Deposit (manuscript-dtd)");[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Assert.AreEqual("NIHMS-PubMed Central Deposit (manuscript-dtd)", "
     ");

I have attached HTML screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Rather than AreEqual(), I'd probably see if you can use .IsTrue() after you've selected the option.

```cs
Assert.IsTrue(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("FtpTransmittalMethods")).FindElement(By.CssSelector("option[selected='selected']")).Selected);
```

or

```cs
Assert.IsTrue(ftpTransDropdown.FindElement(By.CssSelector("option[selected='selected']")).Selected);
```

Doing it this way, you'll still be looking at the element, but, you'll be asserting that the option with the selected attribute with a value of selected is actually the one selected in the SelectElement.